# Visual Studio Code AutoComplete is broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I am starting to learn node.js and I installed Visual Studio Code as my text editor and it wont let me type "require('something')"

Everytime I type "require" then "(" it auto completes to "requestAnimationFrame()".

The language is set to JavaScript. What is wrong with this thing? I tried turning off auto complete in the settings and it didnt change anything at all.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am also very new to Node.js. Had the same issue as you mentioned.
The only work around I found that solved the problem is typing

```
npm install @types/node --save
```

in the terminal. This will install some packages in the node_module folder and solve the problem.

Comment: It is a better idea to use `--save-dev` instead of `--save` for this, because this package is only used for your development environment.